# Capture drag amount using dragstart and dragend in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to capture initial position from where drag is started and the amount of drag (in x & y direction) and pass it to another function for further processing. My html is below:

```
<style>
body{
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
.wrapper{
    width:1800px;
    height:2500px;
    background:#86CDEA;
}
</style>
<div class="wrapper" draggable="true"></div>
```

And my Script is :

```
<script>
    var parentOffset, relX, relY;
    $(".wrapper").on("dragstart", function(event) {
        parentOffset = $(this).offset();
        relX = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        relY = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
        alert("Drag Started - x: "+relX+"px & y: "+relY+"px");
    });

    $(".wrapper").on("dragend", function(event) {
        relX = event.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        relY = event.pageY - parentOffset.top;
        alert("Drag End - x: "+relX+"px & y: "+relY+"px");
    });
  function someFunction(x,y,sftX,sftY){
      //Where x, y is the initial position of the drag and sftX,sftY is the amount of drag in x & y direction respectively which can be +ve or -ve
  }
  </script>
```

My objective is to scroll document or element towards the direction using animate with some extra pixels added into the dragged amount towards the direction in which user want to move the document or element.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged jquery-ui-draggable, I'd use the jQuery UI `draggable` function. Like this:

```
var relX, relY;
$('.wrapper').draggable(
{
    drag: function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        relX = offset.left;
        relY = offset.top;           
    }
});
```

Have a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tjuh5kpv/

Comment: I don't want to drag the .wrapper. It will be fixed in its place. I want to capture drag amount within the .wrapper element. Your code is dragging the .wrapper itself. Also at dragend I want the alert of drag amount. When I added alert of relX in your code it is preventing drag due to alert (dragging 1 or 2 pixcel only).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by jQuery-UI like below:

**HTML**

```
Start Position: <span id="start"></span>
<br/> 
End Position: <span id="end"></span>

<div class="wrapper" draggable="true">Drag me!</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.wrapper').draggable({
  start: function(e, ui) {
    // Getting start position
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    $("#start").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
  },
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    // Getting stop position
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset();
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
    $("#end").html(" x: " + relX + ", y: " + relY);
  }
});
```

[**Online Demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/h3wwwost/3/)

Comment: Sorry gentlemen, I think using draggable with .wapper is making all confusion. **I don't want to move the box.** _My all requirement is for mobile & tablet device._  I want to detect amount of drag, direction of drag and speed of drag when a container wrapper is touched, dragged and released in mobile & tablet. After capturing those data it will be passed to a function where I will perform some action with those data.